# What is the significance of Lady Kaede catching and killing the insect?

Tags: analysis, ran

In *Ran* (1985), after Lady Kaede slept with Lord Jiro, and as she was crying that it is *she* who should be Lord Jiro's wife, not Lady Sue, there is a scene where Lady Kaede has noticed an insect near her (a moth?), caught it, and seemingly killed it.

[image][image]
[image][image]

Does the insect represent Lady Sue? Or Lord Jiro? Or does this act or the insect have other symbolism? Is it a reference to Shakespeare's *King Lear* (which is the inspiration for Ran's plot) or to an aspect of Japanese culture?

Comment: This depicts cinematically a similar image to the one evoked by Gloucester in _King Lear_ IV, i, 37-38: “As flies to wanton boys are we to the gods; They kill us for sport.”

Answer (score 1):

If the moth represents something, it's definitely Lady Sué, but I think the main point is to underline Kaede's deceitfulness and cruelty.

Consider what the situation is - Kaede is at that moment faking tears to help her convince Jiro that she has to become his wife - and a few sentences later she almost explicitly demands that he should not just divorce but *kill* his current wife.

And while doing this, she still takes a moment to casually crush (that's how the screenplay describes it) a harmless insect for no reason.

So the action both stresses Kaede's villainy and mirrors her concurrent attempt to get Sué murdered.

Answer (score 1):

According to the filmmakers on the commentary,  the moth just flew into frame and the actress had the presence of mind to react in character and crush it. I think it is one of those happy accidents that adds so much to the color to the character and metaphorical significance of the scene.